# Pass command line arguments to awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to make a simple bash script that uses command line arguments as parameters to awk.

The file format is like this:

```
id|Name|birthday|joinDate
```

And the command line input:

```
./my_script -f filename.dat -id 1234
```

When I use the following line of code:

```
awk -v arg ="$4", -F"|" '{if(arg == $1)print $1,$2}' "$2"
```

I get an error that says:

```
'awk: 'arg' argument to '-v' not in 'var=value' form'.
```

What's wrong with this? All I want is to print specific columns of the given ID.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your answer is in the error message. Put the argument in `var=value` form, without any spaces around `=` sign.